# Can I override "hide and disable all items on the desktop"?

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, windows-7, group-policy

Is it possible to add shortcuts and/or windows components to the desktop if "hide and disable all items on the desktop" is enabled via GPO? For example, if I have a few specific program icons I want to show up and nothing else, what is the best way to accomplish this?

I tried the steps at [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverGP/thread/c940c96f-b9d3-4067-9ad4-411d5b98309b/) and [here](http://hlouwers.wordpress.com/2010/07/24/show-hide-desktop-items-windows-2008-r2-windows-7-by-means-of-registry-and-microsoft-group-policy-preferences/).

But neither worked. Either the shortcut never showed up or the registry key didnt exist (on either Win7 or S2K8 machine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirecting the desktop to a read-only folder worked nicely.

Also, needed to add the reg entries to [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideDesktopIcons\NewStartPanel]... I only did the ClassicStartMenu/

I also had to add Computer Configuration -> Policies -> Windows Settings -> Security Settings -> File System -> %SYSTEMDRIVE%\Users\Public\Desktop (Users: Deny - List Folder Contents) otherwise icons previously installed by programs available to all users would still show up.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not with you - "Hide and Disable all items on the desktop" does what it says on the tin. It hides and disables *all* items. If you just want a few to show up then you'll need to disable that setting and configure your desktops accordingly.

Comment: Hmm, how would I keep those items from being moved, deleted or right-clicked on??

FYI I tried to give you an up vote but I dont have enough rep points yet!

Comment: For mandated desktops, people generally use folder redirection to enforce specific shortcuts.